# Отличия типа BigDecimal от double/float, что и где лучше использовать?

Tags: java

Я прочитал статью про `BigDecimal`, и у меня вопрос почему `double/float` являются не точными типами? Почему не сделали `double/float` точными, что бы мы не использовали лишний тип `BigDecimal`, а все работало бы `double/float`?

Answer (score 3):

Количество чисел с плавающей точке континуум, то есть их бесконечно много - причем в любом в сколь угодно малом отрезке (теорема Кантора - если мне память не изменяет), а в реализации `Float/Double` их по определению конечное количество, отсюда и выходит, что даже например примитивный `sqrt(2)` всегда будет аппроксимироваться некой точностью (для `double` 15 знаков после запятой). Отсюда и вытекает, что вычисления с плавающей точкой всегда приблизительны и не точны.

Есть альтернатива в виде `BigDecimal` позволяет вести вычисления с плавающей точкой любой точности, правда медленно.

Answer (score 1):

`double` и `float` - являются нативными для процессора типами. Т.е. процессор имеет команды заточенные под данные типы. Размер этих типов 64 и 32 бита соответственно. Т.е. имеются некие предельные значения, которые могут храниться в этих типах. `BigDecimal` же является более сложной структурой размером гораздо больше 64-х бит, которой процессор напрямую оперировать не может. Однако `BigDecimal` может хранить более точные значения.

Чтобы провести аналогию лучше рассмотреть отношение `int`/`long` к `BigInteger`. Первые два типа имеют размер 32 и 64 бита. Второй же тип мы условно можем считать безразмерным. Максимальное значение для java-типа `long` (2^63-1). Если 2^10=1024 ~10^3, т.е. примерно 1_000, то `2^63 ~ 2^3 * 10^18 ~ 8*10^18`

Теперь посчитаем сумму:

```
1_000_000_000_000_000_000 //18 нулей и меньше 8*10^18
+
1_000_000_000_000_000_000 //18 нулей и меньше 8*10^18
=
2_000_000_000_000_000_000 //18 нулей и меньше 8*10^18
```

Как видно, результат вполне влазит в диапазон java-типа `long`. Более того, т.к. процессор заточен под сложение чисел такого диапазона, то можно назвать (условно) данную операцию элементарной, т.е. ***выполняющийся за 1 такт***.

А теперь посчитаем сумму:

```
16_000_000_000_000_000_000 //18 нулей и больше 8*10^18
+
16_000_000_000_000_000_000 //18 нулей и больше 8*10^18
=
32_000_000_000_000_000_000 //18 нулей и больше 8*10^18
```

Эту операцию на процессоре уже так просто не выполнить. Даже любое из чисел не так просто будет записать. Придётся писать специальную программу, которая будет делать нечто подобное:

```
// 1 шаг - подгрузка младших частей и их сложение
6_000_000_000_000_000_000 //младшая часть
+
6_000_000_000_000_000_000 //младшая часть
=
2_000_000_000_000_000_000 //не 12, а 2, и есть флаг переполнения

// 2 шаг - подгрузка старших частей и их сложение
1 //старшая часть
+
1 //старшая часть
=
2 

// 3 шаг - коррекция старшей части
2 //результат из шага 2
+
1 //1 - т.к. был флаг переполнения из шага 1
=
3

// 4 шаг 
Запись 2_000_000_000_000_000_000 в память // результат из младшей части
Запись 3 в память // результат из старшей части
```

Как видно, для, казалось бы, простейшего сложения пришлось писать уже целую функцию. И эта функция ***уже не будет работать за 1 такт***. Java как раз из коробки предоставляет набор таких функций через класс `BigInteger`. С отношением `float`/`double` к `BigDecimal` такая же ситуация.  Всё это конечно упрощение, но общую логики доносит.

Вторая проблема - потеря точности. Из-за особенностей представления `double`/`float` при сложении очень больших (по модулю) чисел с очень маленькими результат может оказаться равен очень большому. Т.е. меньшее слагаемое вообще может быть проигнорировано. С `BigDecimal` такая проблема так же присутствует, но в меньшей степени.

Если же говорить коротко, то по возможности используй более простые типы, т.к. операции над ними быстрее. Типы `BigInteger` и `BigDecimal` стоит использовать, если очень большие числа и/или точность чрезвычайно критична.

Answer (score 0):

- double/float - не точно, но очень быстро.
- BigDecimal - точно, но не
  быстро.

Плюс исторические причины.